# Sum column in google excel using 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a table with 4 columns in a google spreadsheet [timestamp, item, amount, category] and would like to get all rows that belong to a specific month and a specific category and sum the amount column.

So far I have tried

`=QUERY(Sheet1!A:D,"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE MONTH(A) = 1 AND D = 'some text' GROUP BY A",1)`

and

```
=IF(AND(EQ(Sheet1!D2:D,B17),MONTH(Sheet1!A2:A)=1),SUM(Sheet1!C2:C))
```

Where B17 is a text that I want a comparison to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google spreadsheets, try

```
=sumproduct(Sheet1!D2:D=B17,MONTH(Sheet1!A2:A)=1, Sheet1!C2:C)
```

and see if that works?

If you'd prefer query, you can try

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:D,"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE MONTH(A) = 0 AND D = '"&B17&"' label SUM(C) ''",1)
```

Note that MONTH() in query is zero-indexed: so January would be month 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this one:

```
=IF(AND(EQ(Sheet1!D2:D,B17),MONTH(Sheet1!A2:A)=1),SUM(Sheet1!C2:C))
```

with

```
=sum(filter(Sheet1!C2:C,(Sheet1!D2:D=B17)*(MONTH(Sheet1!A2:A)=1)))
```